# Time complexity of loops iterating over related sets

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

Here I come again with basic questions :(

If I have the next pseudo-code:

```
iterate over set (A)
    //some *O(1)* operations

iterate over set (B)
    //another *O(1)* operations
```

From what I have learned, the time would be *O(numberOfElementsInA + numberOfElementsInB)*

However, If I know that *B* is subset of *A* and *numberOfElementsInA* is always greater or equal than 
*numberOfElementsInB*, can I simplify the time by writing just *O(numberOfElementsInA)* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

This is because `numberOfElementsInA + numberOfElementsInB <= 2 * numberOfElementsInA`, and from [definition of big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) it makes it `O(numberOfElementsInA)` (with `c=2`, and for every `N`)

---

**EDIT**: To be exact, each loop is `O(numberOfElementsInSet_i)` - thus there are constants `c_i, N_i` for each loop such that `T(loop_i) <= numberOfElementsInSet_i * c_i` for each `numberOfElementsInSet_i > N_i`.

Thus:

```
for each numberOfElementsInSet_1 > max{N1,N2}:
T(loop_1) + T(loop_2) <= numberOfElementsInSet_1 * c_1 + numberOfElementsInSet_2 * c_2
<= numberOfElementsInSet_1 * c_1 + numberOfElementsInSet_1 * c_2 //set1 is bigger
<= 2 * numberOfElementsInSet_1 * max{c_1,c_2}
```

And now we have a formal proof that the loops together are also `O(numberOfElementsInSet_1)` with `N = max{N1,N2}` and `c = max{c_1,c_2} * 2`